Curve point not always bound to its cluster deformer
I have a scene with two triangles, the big triangle is called curve1 and the small one curve2.
I need a component of curve1 (the tip point) to be always attached or parented to curve2. So that if I move the small triangle, the tip of the big triangle always moves with it.
I managed to achieve this using a cluster deformer that is then made a child of the small triangle. Now when I move the small triangle, the tip of the big triangle follows.
But it has a short coming that I have not been able to fix or find a solution for. If I move the move bigger triangle, all of its points move with it, I am expecting the tip to still remain constrained to the cluster (the small triangle).
I have tried to find ways to fix this but the issue remains, I guess what I am asking is, Is there a way to get a component to still be constrained to a cluster while moving its object?

